May I stop getting "... new item in your Staging Ground Testing inbox" notifications?
Today, I got an email notification from Stack Overflow for Teams for the Staging Ground Beta testers
The relevant part of the message body is

1 For You notification
a question you answered is due for a Content Health review    Jun 8 at 1:00
Beta Participation and Guidance

Since Staging Ground went live last week, how do I stop getting these "Content Health review" notifications?
Is there any reason to stay as a member of this SOfT instance for those who participated as beta testers and how to stop the Content Health Review notifications?
Related

Help needed: a call for volunteer reviewers for the Staging Ground beta test
The return of Staging Ground to Stack Overflow


Check the email settings for SOfT on https://stackoverflowteams.com/users/email/settings/current and https://stackoverflowteams.com/users/email/digests/current
